# Watermark existing PDF's before FTPing them in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, watermark

what library/program to use? Do you have some code for me ?

Specific requirements:
Visual Studio copies certain pdf's to a catalog.
Each PDF file needs a watermark.
Each page of a pdf file needs a watermark.
Watermark needs to be the name of the file.
Watermark position fixed, say top-middle or bottom-middle.

After that it FTP's them and archives them, which is covered already.

Comment: Most PDF processing libraries can do that, e.g. iText(Sharp) for which that is a simple use of the `PdfStamper` class. Before coding, though, you should consider the requirements. Often Watermarks are applied by adding content *behind* the current content. But such watermarks can be partially or even completely covered by foreground content, e.g. an image. Alternatively you may add sopmething *before* the current content. That on the other hand might cover important regular content. Content above can be made semi-transparent. That might mix existing content and the watermark. What do you want?

Comment: As we are talking about watermarking invoices and they tend to have free space at the top or bottom (places i mentioned) that will not be a problem. Say black text (filename), font 8-10

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments to the question, the existing PDFs actually simply need to be stamped. You can do that using iText(Sharp). The following sample code is taken from [StampText.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=StampText), the .Net'ified version of the sample in section 6.3.1 of [iText in Action, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/); chapter 6 "[Manipulating existing PDF documents](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf)" can be downloaded as a free sample chapter:

```
public static byte[] Stamp(byte[] resource) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
      PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
      ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
        canvas,
        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 
        new Phrase("Hello people!"), 
        36, 540, 0
      );
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

This sample manipulates a PDF in memory. It also is possible to read the document from file or write the stamped PDF to file.

iText(Sharp) is available both as free software (AGPL license) or commercially.

Comment: Thank you! Will try your solution.